# 1D array collision

Tags: c#, arrays, collision-detection

I'm struggling with a collision detection type method for a 1D array.

I have a console game with up to 4 players, each player rolls a dice in turn and makes a move on the board.

The rule is that there can only be one player on the board at the same time.

So if player one rolls a 1 he is on square one. 
If player 2 rolls a 1 on his turn he is on square two.
If player 3 rolls a 1 on his turn then he is on square three.
And so on...

```
private static void PlayerMove(int playerNo)
{
    // TODO: Makes a move for the given player

        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfPlayers; i++)
        {
            NextMove = playerPositions[i] + playerPositions[i] + DiceThrow();
            playerPositions[i] = NextMove;
        }
}
```

This is my current method for moving the player, this is a test method at the minute demonstrating that that the players are each able to make a move. The result of this is that each player lands on square number 1.

```
static bool PlayerInSquare(int squareNo)
{
    //TODO: write a method that checks through the 
    //rocket positions and returns true if there is a rocket in the given square

    if (This conditional is what has me confused)
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is the method that is giving me a headache. I've been experimenting with the conditional and had it half working but just can't seem to get it right.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the rule only one player on the board, or only one player on a square?

Comment: The rule is only one player on a square. It's a board game console application. Cheers for the reply

Comment: I don't understand the move rule. How does player 2 end up on square 2 if she rolls a 1? Is it because player 1 already occupies square 1? Would player 2 end up on square 2 if she rolled a 2 also? And square 3 if she rolled a 3?

Comment: Each player starts on square 0 (off the board). Assuming that each player rolls a 1 on their first throw, the first player to roll would land on square 1, the second player would have to 'jump' to square 2 and the third player would have to jump to square 3

Comment: You just repeated what you already said but with the word "jump". I'm just going to assume you'd answer in the affirmative to the rest of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `playerPositions[]` is an array of integers which contains the number of the square that player is on, you can try:

```
static bool PlayerInSquare(int squareNo)
{
    return playerPositions.Any(pos => pos == squareNo);
}
```

A less Linq-y solution (which amounts to the same thing) would be:

```
static bool PlayerInSquare(int squareNo)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfPlayers; i++)
        if (playerPositions[i] == squareNo)
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry i should of been more specific in the question. PlayerPositions is an integer array holding each players position. There is no board array at this time.

Comment: @Fendorio Then this answer should do what you are looking for

Comment: Thankyou. The only way me and my friend could think of doing this was involving recursion... which isn't the route i wanted to follow. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could just use:

```
static bool PlayerInSquare(int squareNo)
{
    return playerPositions.Any(pos => pos == squareNo);
}
```